# Error in integration of ChatGPT API in SAS. Invalid context type header

Tags: sas, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I would like to integrate chatgpt into sas, but when I execute the code I get the error shown in the image.

The error message that is shown is> Invalid-COntent Type header. Expexted application/json.

[image]

```
%let chatgpt_api_token = sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
%let chatgpt_api_url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
%let chat_prompt = "Hello, how can I assist you?";

/* Define the SAS macro to interact with the ChatGPT API */
%macro chat_with_gpt(prompt);
  /* Prepare the JSON payload for the API request */
  filename payload temp;
  data null;
    file payload;
    put '{ "prompt": "'  &prompt  '", "max_tokens": 50, "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo" }';
  run;

  /* Submit the API request using PROC HTTP */
  filename response temp;
  proc http
    method="POST"
    url=&chatgpt_api_url
    in=payload
    out=response
    headerout=header;
    headers "Authorization" = "Bearer &chatgpt_api_token"
            "Content-Type" = "application/json";
  run;
  /* Read the API response and save it to a SAS dataset */
  data chatgpt_response;
    infile response;
    input;
    put infile;
    /* Parse the JSON response and store it in a variable */
    response = infile;
  run;

  /* Display the API response in the SAS log */
  proc print data=chatgpt_response;
  run;
%mend;

/* Call the macro to initiate a chat with ChatGPT */
%chat_with_gpt(&chat_prompt);
```

Tried different solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you inspect the payload you created?

The resolution of the macro variable in the context of the `put` statement will not double not the value of the json option `prompt`.

Try

```
%let chat_prompt = '"Hello, how can I assist you?"';
```

Comment: I tried and still dont work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of issues.  In particular, the chat/completion endpoint should be delivered the 'prompt' via a "messages" item.

Try this complete example:

Your double quoting of the prompt has been replaced with macro encapslating `%str()`.

```
%include "D:\GPTKeyForSAS.txt";

/* Api documentation for chat/completions:
 * https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create
 */

/* Define the SAS macro to interact with the ChatGPT API */
%macro chat_with_gpt(prompt, completer="https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions");
  /* Prepare the JSON payload for the API request */
  filename payload temp;
  data null;
    file payload;

    prompt = symget('prompt');

    put '{ "messages": [{"role":"user", "content":' prompt: $quote5000. '}]'
      / ', "max_tokens": 100'
      / ', "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo"'
      / '}';
  run;

data _null_;
  infile payload lrecl=32767;
  input;
  putlog _infile_;
run;

%local options;
%let options = %sysfunc(getoption(mprint)) %sysfunc(getoption(symbolgen));
options nosymbolgen nomprint;
/* Submit the API request using PROC HTTP */
  filename response 'c:\temp\chatgpt-response.json';
  filename resphdr  temp;
  proc http
    method="POST"
    url=&completer
    in=payload
    out=response
    headerout=resphdr
  ;
    headers "Authorization" = "Bearer &chatgpt_api_key"
            "Content-Type" = "application/json";
  run;
options &options;

  /* Log the response header */
  data _null_;
    put 'NOTE: ---------------';
    put 'NOTE: Response header';
    put 'NOTE: ---------------';
    do while (not done);
      infile resphdr end=done;
      input;
      putlog _infile_;
    end;
    stop;
  run;

  /* Log and store the API response in a data set */
  proc delete data=chatgpt_response;
  data chatgpt_response;
    timestamp = datetime(); format timestamp datetime19.;
    putlog 'NOTE: --------';
    putlog 'NOTE: Response @' timestamp;
    putlog 'NOTE: --------';
    do while (not done);
      infile response end=done lrecl=32767;
      input;
      putlog _infile_;
      response = _infile_;
      output;
  end;
  stop;
  run;

  libname parse json "%sysfunc(pathname(response))";
  proc copy inlib=parse outlib=work;
  run;

  ods html file='response-content.html';
  proc print data=choices_message;
    var content / style=[asis=yes];
  run;
  ods html close;

%mend;

%chat_with_gpt( %str(Write me a haiku about SAS programming) )
```

[image]